# How to reduce docker image size for java apps without alpine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have an image build upon a `eclipse-temurin:11`, which runs fine, but results in >600mb for a simple `spring-boot` hello world webapp.

Question: is my dockerfile wrong, or how could I reduce image size, **without** having to switch on an alpine/musslibc?

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM maven:3.8.4-eclipse-temurin-11 as build
WORKDIR application

COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src src
RUN mvn package

RUN cp /application/target/*.jar application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:11
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=build application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build application/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=build application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=build application/application/ ./

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Maybe anybody sees a problem regarding the image layer sizes?

```
~$ docker history myimage:latest 
IMAGE          CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
e628830c54bf   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["java" "org.s…   0B        
87d052d04e27   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:5d09192487cc563d9…   13.8kB    
8c34a91b2cfb   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8b993266a653e9e77…   0B        
d4e71b50b4da   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8b86bf42f46c065b7…   252kB     
fbc788f64a4a   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:961713675a0647292…   26.4MB    
fa2564232f74   2 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /application          0B        
3dbb3240fc1f   4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["jshell"]               0B        
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c echo Verifying install ...     &&…   0B        
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/o…   0B        
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -eux;     ARCH="$(dpkg --prin…   322MB     
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0…   0B        
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update     && DEBIAN_FRON…   43.2MB    
<missing>      4 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANG…   0B        
<missing>      5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      5 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:1d3b09cf9e041d608…   72.8MB
```

The problem seems to be the layer with 322mb, where the full `jdk` is downloaded into the container:

> 4 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -eux;     ARCH="$(dpkg
> --print-architecture)";     case "${ARCH}" in        aarch64|arm64)          ESUM='79572f5172c6a040591d34632f98a20ed148702bbce2f57649e8ac01c0d2e3db';
> BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_aarch64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz';          ;;        armhf|arm)         
> ESUM='f4d53a1753cdde830d7872c6a1279df441f3f9aeb5d5037a568b3a392ebce9c2';
> BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz';
> ;;        ppc64el|powerpc:common64)         
> ESUM='9750e11721282a9afd18a07743f19c699b2b71ce20d02f3f0a906088b9ae6d9a';
> BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_ppc64le_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz';          ;;        s390x|s390:64-bit)         
> ESUM='79a27a4dc23dff38a5c21e5ba9b7efcf0aa5e14ace1a3b19bec53e255c487521';
> BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_s390x_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz';          ;;        amd64|i386:x86-64)         
> ESUM='43fb84f8063ad9bf6b6d694a67b8f64c8827552b920ec5ce794dfe5602edffe7';
> BINARY_URL='https://github.com/adoptium/temurin11-binaries/releases/download/jdk-11.0.14.1%2B1/OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.14.1_1.tar.gz';
> ;;        *)          echo "Unsupported arch: ${ARCH}";          exit
> 1;          ;;     esac;     curl -LfsSo /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz
> ${BINARY_URL};     echo "${ESUM} */tmp/openjdk.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c
> -;     mkdir -p /opt/java/openjdk;     cd /opt/java/openjdk;     tar -xf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz --strip-components=1;     rm -rf /tmp/openjdk.tar.gz;   322MB

How could I reduce the java layer here?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not completely familiar with how spring-boot works, but you do copy dependencies into your image...one solution I have used on a server is to map local directories as volumes and more or less used Git to hold the code docker runs from. In my situation it removed quite a bit of size and allowed me to host the docker image publicly without worry of code being looked at

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution could be to use the 11-jre image for runtime (`eclipse-temurin:11-jre`). This would save around 100 MB. Everything else seems to be related to your application (given that the `11` image is around 220 MB in size).

Comment: My jar is `25mb`, and I only have the dockerfile as written above. Where could the additional space come from? By the way: a search for `11-jre` does not return any results?? https://hub.docker.com/search?q=eclipse-temurin%3A11-jre&type=image